# Razor multiline syntax for grid column format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid, razor-2

I have a `WebGrid` that I am trying to define in an MVC4 razor view. I would like to define a column format using multiple lines for readability. The following works, with the format on one line:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(
            header: "Address",
            format: (item) => @: @item.Address.Street1 @item.Address.Street2<br />@item.Address.City, @item.Address.State @item.Address.Zip
            )
        )
    )
```

The following gives a parser error, `; expected`, on the first trailing parenthesis, and `Invalid expression term ')'` on the other trailing parentheses:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(
            header: "Address",
            format: (item) => @: @item.Address.Street1 @item.Address.Street2<br />
                              @: @item.Address.City, @item.Address.State @item.Address.Zip
            )
        )
    )
```

After reading [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx), I thought this was the proper multiline syntax. I have tried various placements of curly braces, semicolons, and parentheses, and I can't find a syntax that makes the parser happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After toying with it for a little while longer I was able to find a working version using the `<text>` tag.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(
            header: "Address",
            format: @<text>@item.Address.Street1 @item.Address.Street2<br />
                           @item.Address.City, @item.Address.State @item.Address.Zip</text>
                )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the multi-line lambda.

What about something like this:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(
        header: "Address",
        format: (item) => 
                        {
                          @: @item.Address.Street1 @item.Address.Street2<br />
                          @: @item.Address.City, @item.Address.State @item.Address.Zip
                        }
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<dynamic, object>'